# guacamole You do not have permission to access this connection"

Tags: docker, guacamole

After successfully setting up a **dockerized guacamole 0.9.8** along the lines of

- http://guac-dev.org/doc/gug/guacamole-docker.html
- http://kalzi.github.io/2015/guacamole-with-docker-containers/

with the script below and login in with user: guacadmin password: guacadmin
I was able to setup a user and an rdp connection. Guacamole's UI is useable
directly via the mapped port configured in the docker setup script (8380 in my case) but also via a reverse apache proxy configured as per guacamoles manual with:

```bsh
<Location /guac/ >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8380/guacamole/ flushpackets=on
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8380/guacamole/
  </Location>
```

I tried to follow the manual for rdp connections
http://guac-dev.org/doc/gug/configuring-guacamole.html#rdp

but when using the reverse-proxy ended up with:

[image: Error message]

Which happened also to other users see:

https://sourceforge.net/p/guacamole/discussion/1110834/thread/73abbe35/

**How could I debug this situation to find the correct settings?**

There seems to be something fishy since as an administrator e.g. guacadmin I do get
[image: Error message on permissions]
when trying to enable and save permissions for connections in the following dialog:
[image]

I have access to the mysql DB being used for permissions e.g. 
with

```sql
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_guacamole_db                |
+---------------------------------------+
| guacamole_connection                  |
| guacamole_connection_group            |
| guacamole_connection_group_permission |
| guacamole_connection_history          |
| guacamole_connection_parameter        |
| guacamole_connection_permission       |
| guacamole_system_permission           |
| guacamole_user                        |
| guacamole_user_permission             |
+---------------------------------------+
```

**This is the Dockerizing Script for guacamole i used**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# 
#   WF 2015-10-26
#
# Guacamole (semi) automatic setup of guacamole Remote Desktop server for docker
# see
#  http://guac-dev.org/doc/gug/guacamole-docker.html
#  http://kalzi.github.io/2015/guacamole-with-docker-containers/
#
# Since: 2015-10-26
#

# config variables

# images
GUAC=glyptodon/guacamole 
GUACD=glyptodon/guacd
MYSQL=mysql

# DB settings
DB=guacamole_db
DB_USER=guacamole_user

# prefix to be used for container names
prefix="lab"

#ansi colors
#http://www.csc.uvic.ca/~sae/seng265/fall04/tips/s265s047-tips/bash-using-colors.html
blue='\033[0;34m'
red='\033[0;31m'
green='\033[0;32m' # '\e[1;32m' is too bright for white bg.
endColor='\033[0m'

#
# a colored message 
#   params:
#     1: l_color - the color of the message
#     2: l_msg - the message to display
#
color_msg() {
  local l_color="$1"
  local l_msg="$2"
  echo -e "${l_color}$l_msg${endColor}"
}

#
# error
#
#   show an error message and exit
#
#   params:
#     1: l_msg - the message to display
error() {
local l_msg="$1"
# use ansi red for error
color_msg $red "Error: $l_msg" 1>&2
exit 1
}

#
# show usage
#
usage() {
echo "usage: guac-setup"
# -h|--help|usage|show this usage
echo "  -h|--help: show this usage"
# -m|--mysql|run mysql in linked container
echo "  -m|--mysql:run mysql in linked container"
# -r|--run|run|run guacamole
echo "  -p|--pull: pull guacamole"
echo "  -pf|--prefix: set the containername prefix"
echo "  -r|--run: run guacamole"
color_msg $blue "Example:"
echo "   sudo ./guac-setup -p -pf test -r"
exit 1
}

#
# generate a random password
#
random_password() {
date +%N | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 16 ; echo
} 

#
# run mysql in container
#
mysql_from_container() {
  local l_option="$1"
  local l_db="$2"
  local l_dbparam=""
  if [ "$l_db" != "" ]
  then
    l_dbparam=" $l_db"
  fi
  local l_cmd='exec mysql -h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" -P"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT" -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"'"$l_dbparam"
  #echo "$l_cmd"
  docker run $l_option --link $prefix-mysql:mysql --rm mysql sh -c "$l_cmd" 
} 

#
# initialize the database
#
init_db() {
local l_tmp=/tmp/initdb.sql
#docker run -it $GUAC /bin/bash 
color_msg $blue creating database

cat << EOF | mysql_from_container -i
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS $DB;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $DB;
DROP USER '${DB_USER}';
CREATE USER '${DB_USER}' IDENTIFIED BY '${DB_PASSWD}';
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON guacamole_db.* TO 'guacamole_user';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EOF
  color_msg $blue "getting initdb.sh" 
  docker run --rm $GUAC /opt/guacamole/bin/initdb.sh --mysql > $l_tmp 
  color_msg $blue "initializing database"
  # pipe the result thru mysql
  cat $l_tmp | mysql_from_container -i "$DB"
  color_msg $blue "keeping password for db $DB at /var/lib/mysql/guac_passwd"
  #echo $DB_PASSWD
  echo $DB_PASSWD | docker exec -i $prefix-mysql /usr/bin/tee /var/lib/mysql/guac_passwd > /dev/null
}

#  
# run guacamole
# 
run () {
  local l_prefix="$1"
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=`random_password`
  color_msg $blue "starting $l_prefix-guacd"
  docker run --name $l_prefix-guacd -d $GUACD
  color_msg $blue "starting $l_prefix-mysql"
  docker run --name $l_prefix-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -d mysql:latest
  docker ps -a --filter "name=$l_prefix*"
}

# 
# pull images
# 
pull() {
  for image in $GUACD $GUAC $MYSQL 
  do
    docker images | cut -c1-22 | grep $image
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
      docker pull $image
    else
      color_msg $green "$image already pulled"
    fi
  done
}

#
# start it
#
startit() {
  DB_PASSWD=`docker exec -i $prefix-mysql /bin/cat /var/lib/mysql/guac_passwd`
  # now run the whole show
  docker run --name $prefix-guacamole --link $prefix-guacd:guacd \
     --link $prefix-mysql:mysql      \
     -e MYSQL_DATABASE=$DB  \
     -e MYSQL_USER=$DB_USER    \
     -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWD \
     -d -p 8380:8080 $GUAC 
}

# start of script

# check arguments
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
  usage
fi
while test $# -gt 0
do
  case $1 in
    # -h|--help|usage|show this usage
    -h|--help) 
      usage;;

    # -p|--pull|pull|pull guacamole
    -p|--pull) 
       pull;;

    # -pf|--prefix|set containername prefix
    -pf|--prefix) 
       shift
       prefix=$1
       ;;

    # -r|--run|run|run guacamole
    -r|--run) 
       run $prefix;;

    # -m|--mysql|run mysql connection to container
    -m|--mysql) 
       mysql_from_container -it
       ;;

    -ms|--mysql_shell) 
      docker exec -it $prefix-mysql /bin/bash
      ;;

    -i|--initdb)
       DB_PASSWD=`random_password`
       init_db
       ;;

    --setup) 
       pull
       run $prefix
       ;;

    --start) 
       startit
       ;;
  esac
  shift
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How could I debug this situation to find the correct settings?**

In the case of authentication errors like this, the first thing you should do is check the Tomcat logs for errors. If an error is occurring which is causing Guacamole to return "Permission denied", that error should be logged and will correlate temporally with the actions that produce the error.

If nothing jumps out as relevant, you can also try [enabling debug-level logging](http://guac-dev.org/doc/gug/configuring-guacamole.html#webapp-logging). This involves creating a `logback.xml` file within [`GUACAMOLE_HOME`](http://guac-dev.org/doc/gug/configuring-guacamole.html#guacamole-home) containing the following:

```
<configuration>

    <!-- Appender for debugging -->
    <appender name="GUAC-DEBUG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- Log at DEBUG level -->
    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="GUAC-DEBUG"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

If you are doing this with the official Docker images, `GUACAMOLE_HOME` will be `/root/.guacamole`, and you will need to restart the container to force Tomcat to restart and reload the Guacamole configuration.

**If you are using Guacamole behind a proxy like Nginx or Apache, I would also recommend first trying to connect to Guacamole directly. An incorrect proxy configuration could prevent WebSocket from working, and then prevent the fallback HTTP tunnel from working.** Such a misconfiguration may appear, from Guacamole's perspective, that you are attempting to access a resource without being logged in, resulting in the permission error.

Comment: Thx I have accepted the answer since I was specifically only asking for debugging the situation. Now I'd like to do two things: 1) fix the situation 2) file a bug report / change request that there should be a proper error message when the HTTP tunnel is not working - better even there should be a connection debug option for fixing setup issues

Comment: The permission denied issue for the admin dialog is still there.

Answer (score 0):

http://guac-dev.org/doc/gug/proxying-guacamole.html#websocket-and-apache

has the necessary configuration (shown here adapted for the 8380 port being used and the /guac path)

```bsh
<Location /guac/websocket-tunnel>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    ProxyPass ws://localhost:8380/guacamole/websocket-tunnel
    ProxyPassReverse ws://localhost:8380/guacamole/websocket-tunnel
</Location>
```

To activate the configuration i used:

```bsh
a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
Considering dependency proxy for proxy_wstunnel:
Module proxy already enabled
Enabling module proxy_wstunnel.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 restart
service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2
```

Now the connection works both directly via port 8380 and via the reverse proxy configuration that maps it to /guac on my main server.